# .NET: List HTTP traffic URLs with C#

Tags: c#, .net, http, url

I am looking for a basic method of retrieving the URLs (HTTP) being requested by any other application on the local computer. Basically I only want a textbox in this app that lists the URLs as they are being requested. I am only interested in the url, nothing more. What would be the simplest way of accomplishing this? I would rather not require the app to run in admin-mode and I don't want to use external libraries such as Fiddler or similar.

**Update:**

I noticed Fiddler was developed with .NET so its obviously possible to do what I want using only .NET. Im sifting through the code of Fiddler using Reflector but its not giving me much. I dont know where to start. But as I said, Im only interesting in outgoing traffic on HTTP and only the specific url of the request. This cant be so hard so fix with .NET only?

**Update:**

The key seem to be to use a Socket from the System.Net.Sockets namespace. Im not exactly sure how to use it correctly yet but Im following some other examples and it seem to be pretty easy.

Comment: You're probably not going to find a basic method unless you can modify the app you're trying to monitor.  Just curious - why don't you want to use fiddler?

Comment: Well I want to keep it simple, and I want to know what Im doing. Fiddler seem to be so much more than what I need. Just monitoring the requested urls doesnt feel like a very complicated task, but maybee it is?

Answer (score 2):

I know you said don't want to use external libraries, but there is no simple way of intercepting the URLs requested by other processes without using other libraries.

In case you are interested, I used [PCap .NET](http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/) some time ago. It was really easy to use, and in few hours I had an application listening for HTTP communications between third party applications, and automating one of them depending on the captured info.

Comment: I was hoping it was possible with .NET only, but maybee it isnt.

Comment: @nateirvin I just tried, and it is working. Maybe yesterday the server was down..?